# Using a properties grid with a tree control

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

I want to create a tree control that when the user clicks on an element in the tree control, a properties grid is populated with its properties.

I've created a tree control as a user control and I'm using Jaime Oliveras' property grid.  I have both on a WPF window but I can't seem to figure out how to make the two communicate with each other.

The XAML on the Main window is:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:advanced="clr-namespace:OptionsStrategyTree.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OptionsStrategyTree.ViewModel"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls"              
        x:Class="OptionsStrategyTree.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserStrategyTree HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,6,0,13" 
                                Width="195" Height="340" />
        <Controls:WpfPropertyGrid x:Name="StrategyTreePropertyGrid" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="340" Margin="233,6,0,0" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've had this properties grid working nicely when the controls are all on the same XAML window.  But when I've created a tree control as a user control, it's a separate entity in its own XAML space that seems to be isolated from everything else.  Is there any way to connect the two?

Comment: How do you bind the selection from the tree to your property grid?

Comment: There is no binding to the property grid.  You set the selected item to the property grid's selected Item and your grid populates.  I can't figure out how to reach the property grid's scope from the treeview.

Comment: Are you sure property grid does not have selected item dependecy property? That's strange. But anyway, you can handle selection changed event of `UserStrategyTree` (create it if it does not exist yet) and set selection there.